# Java - Attaching debugger after crash, or speeding up debugger

Tags: java, debugging

I'm not entirely sure how to word this question, so I apologize for the vague title. My problem is that I've encountered a bug that causes the program to crash. However, it only occurs when I don't have a debugger attached to the process. I'm 95% certain the crash is related to the frame rate of the program, and since the debugger slows down the program so much, the crash can't occur while it's running.

So, I was wondering if there was any way to attach a debugger to the program after it crashes, or possibly speed it up in some way by disabling unnecessary features up until the crash. I'm not entirely sure either are possible though, from what I've been able to find, so if anyone has any suggestions as to what else I can do to debug the program, please say so.

Comment: What do you mean by *crash*? What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: It's an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in a libGDX project. It's caused by an NaN value being perpetrated across the project, and I haven't been able to track it down without a debugger.

Comment: Are you on Android? Post your stack trace and the code it points to. (On Android stack trace is in Logcat).

Comment: In Eclipse you can set a uncaught exception breakpoint.  If you were to do that for the offending exception, does it still slow things down?

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm just running on the desktop for the moment, and the code it points to isn't really relevant, as it's one of those bugs that starts off somewhere else in the code and only causes an exception later.

Comment: Does it "crash" when you run it under debugger without any break points?

Comment: @CodeChimp I'm using IntelliJ, but it's debugger can do the same thing. I tried removing all other breakpoints but the exception breakpoint, and there was a noticeable speedup. After running the program a few times, I managed to get the crash to occur with the debugger running. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answering my own question so it doesn't remain unaccepted. Answer was gotten from the comment by CodeChimp.

The issue was that the I had several breakpoints throughout my program that were causing the slowdown. When I disabled all other breakpoints besides a single uncaught exception breakpoint, the debugger was able to run fast enough to catch the crash.